# Apache Nifi QuerySolr processor hitting upper limit of the start parameter

Tags: solr, apache-nifi, data-ingestion

I'm using QuerySolr processor in Apache Nifi to retrieve a document list that exceeds 10000 (which is the upper limit defined in QuerySolr processor [1]). Is there a way to bypass this limit in QuerySolr processor or is there a work around to retrieve more Solr documents than the defined upper limit?

[1] https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-solr-bundle/nifi-solr-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/solr/QuerySolr.java#L130

Comment: why would you need to change it? As far as I can see the code is using cursor, which should help to retrieve all documents, just in several batches of this size

Comment: @Mysterion, if the index has more than 10000 documents to retrieve in the index, then this limits it to 10000 documents. In my case its 40000 documents which will be retrieved in small batches iteratively. It doesn't retrieve documents more than 10000. It's a hard limit defined in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Tried different things, and it seems unless you modify QuerySolr processor code's UPPER_LIMIT_START_PARAM, this cannot be avoided for indexes with more than 10,000 documents.